# error while deploying page layouts of standard object

Tags: deployment, page-layout, contact, ant

i am working on deploying the metadata to another org.
but while deploying the page-layouts i am getting following error on Contact object layout :

```
layouts/Contact-Contact Layout.layout -- Error: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>
```

i checked all possible solutions on stackexchange but they all with custom objects and this is standard object. what should i do?

Comment: Have you looked at known issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5hTAAS and tried workaround mentioned there.

Comment: yes already checked that out but thats also for custom object. and i am getting for standard object.

Comment: I feel you should not divide this problem into standard or custom objects. As even standard object can have custom fields. Are you sure that you don't have any custom fields/history tracking/lookup filters involved. Have you tried deploying contact layout separately.

Comment: yes i have custom fields and yes i tried doing it separately also and i disabled the history tracking also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys this error is gone when i enable the chatter option in my target org. check if chatter option is enable in target org if not enable and then try.. i just enable it for other thing and then at last i tried again deploying layout and it deployed successfully.

Comment: nice find... ..

Comment: worked for you too?

Comment: I didnt try.. but if it resolved for u .. i will keep this in mind if I run into any similar issue in future :)

Comment: yehh sure... spent almost 6 hours for this...

Comment: i was resolving my other problem that also i posted here on this link : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139335/unknown-user-permission-chatterinternaluser-while-deploying-the-profiles/139370#139370 and with one thing i solved my two problems.