# Unknown user permission: ChatterInternalUser while deploying the profiles

Tags: chatter, deployment, profile, ant

getting following error :

```
Unknown user permission: ChatterInternalUser
```

while i am deploying profiles. following the xml file :

```
<types>
    <members>Accounting</members>
    <members>Catering Banquets</members>
    <members>Community User</members>
    <members>Food Beverage</members>
    <members>Front Desk Agents</members>
    <members>Front Desk Management</members>
    <members>Housekeeping</members>
    <members>Membership</members>
    <members>POS Register</members>
    <members>Platform</members>
    <members>Programs</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
```

for every profile this is coming.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Salesforce known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5a8AAC) on this - there can be different permissions between different org types (e.g. dev and sandbox).

The only workarounds suggested in the article are:

- Removing the reference to the user permission in the metadata manually
- Removing the profile from the deployment

Both aren't ideal solutions, but you can vote on the idea to hopefully get it fixed.

Comment: oh yehh sure have to vote for that.. coz this might cause many problem like if have created profiles with different permissions and i cant deploy that permissions then i have to manually add that permission to target org.

Comment: hi solved this error by just enabling the chatter option in target org. and it worked

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @patelkiran3090

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this error by enabling chatter option on the target org. i just enabled it and worked.

Comment: I have chatter enabled and it still doesn't work. Do you mean the checkbox Enable in the Chatter setting?

Comment: yes @mascot check that checkbox and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Resolved it by going to Setup->chatter settings-> Allow users to edit posts and comments.